# The following program "Counting consecutive 1's of a binary no" shows different ans when input goes more than 8-digit value?

Tags: c

I have tried different inputs and when it exceeds a 7 or 8 digit value it just shows some wrong answers as outputs but it worked fine with most of my cases.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int bin(unsigned long long int n){//gave function for binary convertion
    if(n==0)
    return 0;
    else
    return (n%2+10*bin(n/2));
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long long int n,x;/*I even gave high digit data type*/
    int i, v, count=0, max=0;
    scanf("%llu",&n); /*if input is >8-digit output is wrong*/
    x = bin(n);
    v = floor(log10(x))+1; /*Its length*/
    int a[v];
    for(i = v-1; i >= 0; i--){ /*string it in array*/
        a[i] = x%10;
        x = x/10;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < v; i++){
        if(a[i] == 0){
        count = 0;}
        else{
        count++;}
        if(max < count){
        max = count;}
    }
    printf("%d",max);/*I gave 99999999 output is 8 but its shows 9*/
}
```

Comment: I put the code in the right format, but if you can, please use indentation and appropriate whitespace in your code. . . as now done by @Broman aka Klutt.

Comment: Suggest fixing "warning: implicit declaration of function 'floor' " and adding `;` to `count++`.

Comment: What is "ans"? Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE].

Comment: `floor(log10(x))` is not a robust way to determine digit count owing to small rounding errors manifest when converting the  result to  `int`.

Comment: The title suggests that you want to count consecutive *binary* digits having value 1.  You actually seem to be counting consecutive *decimal* digits having value different from 0.

Comment: ... and no `#include <math.h>` for `floor` and `log10`. Please enable all warnings and fix them.

Comment: Any way around, you are going to a lot of trouble to create an array of digit values, and it's doing you more harm than good.  In no way do you need such an array for either variation of the problem.

Comment: Hint: Drop all the fancy float functions like `floor` and `log10`. They serve no purpose here. Look at the binary operators `&` and `<<`

Comment: Thankfully you use `unsigned` type which can be right-shifted without any problem. Examine bit `0` with `n & 1` and then shift `n` right with `n >>= 1` until you have examined every bit.

Comment: @chuk-Thanks for explaining next time i wont use the functions for counting digits

Comment: @klutt-,Sorry for the code it was my first time with stackoverflow from next time i will reduce my mistakes.

Comment: @4386427&@John Bollinger-Sorry for my complicated counting iam still a beginner so eventually i will try to reduce my mistakes.

Comment: @Weather Vane- Thanks for remembering me to use math library.I have literally forgotten to use math library while doing math functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has a number of problems. Here is one example:

```
int bin(unsigned long long int n){
^^^
```

The function returns an `int` so the calculation will overflow for even small numbers:

```
printf("%d\n", bin(1023));  // will print 1111111111 (fine)
printf("%d\n", bin(1024));  // will/may print 1410065408 (ups - very bad)
```

Even if you change to

```
unsigned long long int bin(unsigned long long int n){
```

overflow will happen soon.

In I'll recommend that you look directly into the binary pattern of the number using the `&` operator.

I'll not solve the complete task for you but here is some code that may help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  size_t t = 1;
  size_t limit;
  size_t n;
  if (scanf("%zu", &n) != 1)
  {
    printf("Illegal input\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  limit = 8 * sizeof n;  // Assume 8 bit chars
  for (size_t i = 0; i < limit; ++i)
  {
    if (n & t)
    {
      printf("Bit %zu is 1\n", i);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Bit %zu is 0\n", i);
    }
    t = t << 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```